# SignalR: can't connect to any ip address

Tags: c#, localhost, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying use SignalR with IP address but i am not able to connect with any ip adresses. Firstly i tried for server URI this. "http://127.0.0.1:8080/signalr" but i take some errors. Client app says unable to connect server. what could be reason of this?

```
public partial class WinFormsServer : Form
{
    private IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }
    const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

    private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToConsole("Starting server...");
        ButtonStart.Enabled = false;
        Task.Run(() => StartServer());
    }

    private void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException)
        {
            WriteToConsole("Server failed to start. A server is already running on " + ServerURI);
            //Re-enable button to let user try to start server again
            this.Invoke((Action)(() => ButtonStart.Enabled = true));
            return;
        }
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => ButtonStop.Enabled = true));
        WriteToConsole("Server started at " + ServerURI);
    }

    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I changed my startup class with this code like Rick van den Bosch's solve. But i can't connect any ip address still.

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there something running that listens on port 8080 then?

Comment: netstat -ano | find ":8080"
I tried this command on cmd to know that and its clear.

Comment: If something running that listens on port 8080 localhost must not running but URI with localhost is running. If i try any URI with IP adress its not running.

Comment: Please have a look at setting up CORS. For instance look at this blogpost: [SignalR cross domain with CORS](https://cmatskas.com/signalr-cross-domain-with-cors/)

Comment: I looked ur solve. I just changed my startup but in clientside i can't find anything to change.